# Чи можна вживати слово "калитка" для позначення невеликих дверей в огорожі?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм

У суржикомовному середовищі досить поширеним є слово `калитка` для позначення невеликих дверцят в огорожі.

В мене є підозри, що слово `калитка` - це росіянізм, бо саме в такому значенні воно використовується в російській мові.

*Чи є таке вживання слова `калитка` літературною нормою?*

*Коли і як я можу вживати слово `калитка`?*

*Яке слово для позначення невеликих дверцят в огорожі я можу використовувати?*

Comment: На Сумщині ([в Ужгороді теж](http://www.admir.uz.ua/ru-i-offer-i-id-i-650246-i-kalitka-kovana-arteli.html)) кажуть *калітка*, тому плутанини з *калиткою* немає :)

Comment: хвіртка, кватирка, фіранка.... :-)

Answer (score 19):

**Ні, вживання слова `калитка` для позначення невеличких дверцят в огорожі  - неправильне, не пасує *ні в тин, ні в ворота*.**

Але слово `калитка` не є росіянізмом. Словник української мови подає наступні значення українського слова [`калитка`](http://sum.in.ua/s/kalytka):

> 1. Торбина для грошей; гаманець. *В кого калитка товста, у того мова проста (Номис, 1864, № 12919);*
> 2. Торбинка для тютюну, яку затягують мотузочком; кисет.
> 3. *анат.* Те саме, що мошонка.
>
> > 1. анат. М'язо-шкіряний мішечок, де містяться чоловічі статеві залози.
> > 2. діал. Гаманець, капшук із такого мішечка.

тобто використання слова `калитка` для позначення дверцят є помилкою, росіянізмом. Для позначення невеличких дверцят у тиночку можна використовувати слово [`хвіртка`](http://sum.in.ua/s/khvirtka), для якого СУМ подає наступні значення:

> Невеликі вхідні двері в тину або в воротах
>
> *рідко.* Дверцята в хліві, стайні

Слово `хвіртка` варто використовувати саме у цьому значенні, а не у значенні немов би недбало українізованого російського слова `форточка`.

Для позначення "Шибки у вікні, вставленої в раму, яку можна відчиняти для провітрювання приміщення" існує українське слово [`кватирка`](http://sum.in.ua/s/kvatyrka)

Comment: Підтверджую, **хвіртка**. Розповсюджене вживання на Полтавщині, попри те, що вона вважається чи не "найсуржикомовнішою".

Comment: Обидва слова `хвіртка` і `форточка` походять від нім. Pforte / Pförtchen (ймовірно через польське Furtka), що означає "дверці до саду або двору"

Answer (score 3):

Укр. «калитка» — це невеликий мішечок. Двері в огорожі — це «хвіртка».

Див. «[калитка](http://sum.in.ua/s/kalytka)» і «[хвіртка](http://sum.in.ua/s/khvirtka)» у «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах.

Comment: Дякую за Вашу відповідь (і інші відповіді теж). Але: (1) На цьому сайті прийнято підкріплювати відповіді джерелами. (2) На цьому сайті прийнято додавати відповіді лише якщо вони містять щось нове в порівнянні з існуючими відповідями (якщо не нову інформацію, то хоч нову спробу систематизації). Джерелом у даному разі може виступити посилання на словник (що розкриває значення слів саме таким чином) або цитати з літератури (з яких видно, що значення слова є саме таким). Щодо самого змісту відповіді — то я безумовно з Вами згоден.